# Save multiples models mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's start with this, I have 2 models

```
-Users
-Forms
```

I make a route type POST `/form-event`, I want to send these fields

```
first_name,
last_name,
form: {}
```

`first_name` and `last_name` it belongs to `Users Model`, and `form` is it belongs to `Forms Model`.

Okay so my problem is trying to save the body data into that two models, I'm doing in this way,

```
// Create a User
  const user = new User({
    ...req.body,
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
  });

  // Create a Form Event
  const formEvent = new FormEvent({
    ...req.body.form,
    userId: user._id
  });

  // Save User in the database
  user
    .save()
    .then(data => {
      formEvent
        .save()
        .then(event => res.send(event))
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
          });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
      });
    });
```

Is there a better way to do this kind of thing ?, because I feel that it is not the correct way, because when sending the `POST`, user is saved and then form but what would happen if there is an error in `formEvent`, the user is already saved, then I cannot send the `POST` again because the user already exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Node.js Async await

You need to add **async** keyword before the function and use **await** whenever you want to wait. Also, use try catch for better error hanldling

```
// Add async keyword before function
async function () {
  // Create a User
  const user = new User({
    ...req.body,
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
  });
  // Create a Form Event
  const formEvent = new FormEvent({
    ...req.body.form,
    userId: user._id
  });
  try {
    var saveUser = await user.save()
    var saveFormevenr = await formEvent.save()
    return { saveUser, saveFormevenr };
  } catch (err) {
    return 'error occured';
  }
}
```

Refernce: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/